# FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3

Tags: c#, android, .net

I want to create android application with .Net c# that use SQLite.
It work when I use nuget package, "sqlite-net-plc" and "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green".

But I want use [sqlite-net with source installation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#source-installation), so I add SQLite.cs to project

I got this Error:

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3
[mono-rt]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(SQLiteConnectionString connectionString)
```

anyone have solution for this error?